# Ionic framework Failed publish in google playstore : Apache Cordova The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.3.5.1

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play

I am developing my mobile apps with `ionic framework`. When I published it to the `Google Playstore`, they rejected me with some reason:

> Apache Cordova
>   The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.3.5.1. You can find more information and next steps in this Google Help Center article.

I have already updated the `cordova` version to 6.2.0 and published it again. But the same rejection appeared again.

[image]

Comment: After updating the Cordova, you have to remove android platform, add it again and rebuild it before sending.

Answer (score 0):

After updating the Cordova, you have to remove android platform, add it again and rebuild it before publishing to Playstore.

Also you gotta ensure that you don't have any reference to old cordova version in any of your project files as Google's text search may find it and fail the app eventhough it is not used. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702467/how-to-fix-apps-with-apache-cordova-vulnerabilities) details about importance of removing the unused file referring to older version of cordova.