# How to fix apps with Apache Cordova vulnerabilities?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, apk

My android application has been rejected from google play and i receive this message below :

> The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.3.5.1. You can find
>   more information and next steps in this [Google Help Center article](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6325474).

But before submitting the update , i've update all plugins and the platform of the project.

*My question:*  **any suggestions about that or any help for fixes this issue ?**

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this in case someone else falls into the same trap: I got this error, and it persisted after upgrading to the latest version of **Cordova (6.2.0)**. I upgraded my platforms and all of my plugins, but the error persisted. Eventually I discovered an old, forgotten and unused backup copy of cordova.js buried deep in a subfolder. Although this old file was not being called by my application, Google's text search was finding it and failing my app. File deleted, bug fixed!